# Selenium Can't find elements by CLASS_NAME

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to scrape a website and get every meal_box meal_container row in a list by driver.find_elements but for some reason I couldn't do it. I tried By.CLASS_NAME, because it seemed the logical one but the length of my list was 0. Then I tried By.XPATH, and the length was then 1 (I understand why). I think I can use XPATH to get them one by one, but I don't want to do it if I can handle it in a for loop.

I don't know why the "find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'print_name')" works but not "find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"meal_box meal_container row")"

I'm new at both web scraping and stackoverflow, so if any other details are needed I can add them.

Here is my code:

```
meals = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"meal_box meal_container row")
print(len(meals))

for index, meal in enumerate(meals):
    foods = meal.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'print_name')
    print(len(foods))
    
    if index == 0:
        mealName = "Breakfast"
    elif index == 1:
        mealName = "Lunch"
    elif index == 2:
        mealName = "Dinner"
    else:
        mealName = "Snack"
    for index, title in enumerate(foods):
        recipe = {}
        print(title.text)
        print(mealName + "\n")
        recipe["name"] = title.text
        recipe["meal"] = mealName
```

Here is the screenshot of the HTML:
[image: HTML]

Comment: can you share the link to the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Ok but about class name put a dot between characters.
Like "meal_box.meal_container.row"  Try this.
meals = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"meal_box.meal_container.row")

Answer (score 0):

Try to use driver.find_element_by_css_selector

Comment: I tried it too, but it didn't work like Class_name although I saw my problem thanks to the first answer adding "." instead of whitespaces did it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It can be because "meal_box meal_container row" is inside of other element. So you should try finding the highest element and look for needed one inside.

```
root = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"row")
meals = root.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "meal_box meal_container row")
```